# Wrong position in draggable elements when previous elems get higher on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css-transitions, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have this situation: I have draggables that are droppable to a special places. I've prepared a fiddle with the feature I've described: http://jsfiddle.net/8MGmb/

```
$('.widget').draggable({
    handle: '.bar',
    helper: 'clone',
    cursorAt: { top: 0 },
    refreshPositions: true,

    start: function () {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden')
        $('body').addClass('dragging');
    },
    stop: function () {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible')
        $('body').removeClass('dragging');
    },
    revert: 'invalid',
    zIndex: 100,
});
```

If you hover .widget divs you will see that .bar element will be visible. This kind of elements are "handler" to start the drag of the full widget. On start, you will notice that .places now are visible with a gray background and the .widget div, which is the element you are dragging, can be dropper inside this kind of places. So when a .widget hover the .place **it gets higher** (with a cool CSS3 transition).

And then we have the problem... if you drag the more inner .widgets (which are inside another .widgets .container) will notice that if you move it to up and hover over a .place (which it is up!) it will move down the same distance that the new height of the hovered .place.

Originally I had the config without a helper: http://jsfiddle.net/fRdks/1/ with the aim to solve the part of the problem but it doesn't solve it with the more inner .widgets (first link!).

```
$('.widget').draggable({
    handle: '.bar',
    cursorAt: { top: 0 },
    refreshPositions: true,
    start: function () {
        $('body').addClass('dragging');
    },
    stop: function () {
        $('body').removeClass('dragging');
    },
    revert: 'invalid',
    zIndex: 100,
});
```

I think I can't put helpers inside body because of CSS... but I need solve this. *Do you think this is a bug of the correct positioning in jquery?*

Thanks a lot.

PD: I've **imported** latest CDN jquery.ui and draggable and droppable js files from github directly instead of using fiddle default files with the aim to solve the know scroll bug (which it is already fixed in master branch).